# .cmd file get relative path when running file on a server

Tags: cmd

I have a CMD file that contains following command:

```
START H:\Applications\MyStoreApp\Application.exe
```

The file is location in the H drive (this is a mapped shared drive) in the folder MyStoreApp. 
I want to make my cmd to resolve it's location relatively like this:

```
START .\Application.exe
```

I'm getting an error now since it cannot resolve this on a remote host.

Is there anyway to solve this without having to enter the specific location of my file including the mapped network drive?

Comment: Search the remote host for your .exe. Or store something in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

`%~dp0` is the path to the actual script directory (`%0` is the script itself).

Considering H:\Applications\MyStore\App\launcher.cmd

```
@echo "%~dp0Application.exe"
"H:\Applications\MyStoreApp\Application.exe"
```

Or, for heavy use :

```
@SET $root=%~dp0
@REM Remove the last backslash
@SET $root=%$root:~0,-1%
@START "App" "%$root%\App.exe" /config "%$root%\App.ini" /log "%$root%\App.log"
```

Quotes are required in case of spaces in folder name.

For more information about parameter extensions, see [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).